# Regular expression - match all lines from first occurrence of string until next occurrence

Tags: regex

I have a comma separated text looking something like this:

```
"99","Header 1","Header 1_1"
"15","Textvalue","Textvalue"
"15","Textvalue","Textvalue"
"99","Header 2","Header 2_1"
"15","Textvalue","Textvalue"
"15","Textvalue","Textvalue"
```

How can I define a regex pattern matching everything from, and including, the first occurrence of "99" until the next occurrence, giving the output:

```
"99","Header 1","Header 1_1"
"15","Textvalue","Textvalue"
"15","Textvalue","Textvalue"
```

Comment: does the occurrence of "99" is fixed ?

Comment: Do you need to match multiple cases (e.g. is the second "99" the start of the second match)?

Answer (score 0):

```
/"99".+?(?="99")/s
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI1tM7/1)

or depending on your implementations...

```
/("99".+?)"99"/s
```

or

```
/("99"(?:.|[\r\n])+?)"99"/
```

or

```
/"99"(?:.|[\r\n])+?(?="99")/
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match the occurrences:

```
("99".*?)"99"
```

Depending on your regex implementation, you might need use the `g`, `i` and `s` modifiers. `$1` contains your desired result.

See:
https://regex101.com/r/dZ7rU0/2